# Custom text display with jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3, android-compose-textfield

Help me, how can i display text using jetpack compose like on the image.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xuu1T.png)
The upper one should start above the last letter of the lower one

I tried to use Box and 2 Text using align, but nothing worked for me. And i tried BadgedBox but i had a problem with offsets